# 'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable an error occurred django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting an error while trying to loop and get the total of a decimal object in a Django model, tried so many solutions all failed. The error is

```
'decimal.Decimal' object is not iterable
```

and here is the models and object.

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {0}'.format(self.id)

    @property
    def order_prices(self):
        order = Decimal(0)
        for o in float(self.total_price):
            order += o
        return float(order)


    @property
    def product_name(self):
        product_name = []
        for b in self.orderitem_set.all():
            product_name.append(b.total_name)
        return product_name
        
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def total_name(self):
        product_name = []
        for p in self.product.name:
            product_name.append(p)
        b = "".join(product_name)
        return b
```

the error occurred at the order_price object at the Order model

Comment: `self.total_price` returns a `Decimal`, so `for o in self.total_price` does not make much sense.

Comment: you shouldn't use `self.total_price` in for loop as it is from `DecimalField`

Comment: I assume you have another model with an Item? And what you're trying to do is sum the total price of all items within an order as a property of `Order`?

Comment: umm, so any suggestions of how to sum all the total_price together ?

Comment: yes @Lewis im trying to sum the total price of all items, i have another model with product/price .. but not a foreignkey for this model

Comment: Please update question to include this model.

Comment: im getting the total price from users as a post method

Comment: @AbdullaOsama I've updated my answer to include `_set` which was missed off.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@property
def order_prices(self):
    queryset = self.orderitem_set.all().aggregate(
        total_price=models.Sum('product__price'))
    return queryset['total_price']
```